# How to create a news function for your own R package

Tags: r, r-package

I am creating an R package and now working on the `NEWS` file. I have an `.Rd` file in the `inst` subfolder which I would like to be called by a customised function like `my_pckg_news()`. I saw this in the `gamlss` package which has `gamlssNews()` as the customised function that calls a `NEWS.txt` file.

So could I create a similar function such that, when calling this function shall display the `NEWS.Rd` file in the help section of RStudio? the way we have `?function_name` displaying the respective `Rd` file.

## Edit : added the sample .Rd file

```
\name{my_package}
\title{News for package \pkg{my_package}}

\section{}{
  \itemize{ 
    \item item1
  }       
}


\section{Version 0.1}{
  \subsection{f1}{
    \itemize{
      \item item1
      \item item2
    }
  }
  \subsection{f2}{
    \itemize{
      \item item1
    }
  }
}
```

Another problem I'm facing here is that, `f1` , `f2` doesn't get printed . and this file doesn't get loaded on the Help section(of `RStudio`) , rather gets directly printed to the `R` console

Comment: How is the file formatted? You should probably just include it in your question.

Comment: I suppose the `.Rd` file, as that is probably what needs to be shipped with your package.

Comment: Your sample `NEWS.Rd` [worked for me](https://github.com/nathan-russell/news/blob/master/README.md). Are you able to reproduce the problem with my example package?

Comment: The `Writing R Extensions` suggest that we should have it in `inst` subfolder. Let me try it

Comment: I have it in the `inst/` folder -- I think that is the only acceptable location for `NEWS.Rd`.

Comment: @nrussell i have it now in `inst` folder and it gets attached. But it doesnt get loaded in the help section but gets printed on the `R` console itself. How can we have it displayed on the help section itself ? Would you like to ask a new questoin itself if I'm bothering you a lot?

Comment: No it's fine -- it sounds like the issue might be with `utils:::print.news_db` instead of `news` itself. I believe that is the function actually responsible for rendering the news document. Have you had issues with any other help files, etc. not rendering?

Comment: @nrussell i was able to solve the problem... thank you very much for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some reading, trials(many!) and help from @nrussell, i was able to have a customised functions for my news file .

In brief :

1. create a `inst` subfolder in your main directory( where `DESCRIPTION` etc) files exist.
2. inside the `inst` folder create another subfolder `doc` wherein you shall save your `NEWS.txt` file.
3. Now create a `.R` file with the name of function you want to keep as the customised news function which when called shall display the `NEWS` file. You can have this filename as a `alias` in one of the `.Rd` filew so that you need not create a separate `.Rd` file for this
4. Inside this function write a single line code that loads the `.txt` file. `file.show(system.file("doc", "NEWS.txt", package = "your_pckg_name"))`
5. Also try to build `.onAttach()` function such as to display a welcoming message when your package gets loaded. Herein you can also mention the name of your customised news function.
6. Final result : = call your news function!!!!

Hope this helps future users!